# Is it possible to fake an ISP (Internet Service Provider) and an IP using PHP Script?

Tags: php

I'd like to know if is it possible to fake an ISP and an IP using a php script. Without execute a program.

For Example, an list .txt:

ISP: domainhost.334.com | IP: 192.168.0.1

ISP: domainhost.336.com | IP: 192.168.3.1

And I use the ISP and the IP from the second line.

Is it possible?

Comment: No. You can't spoof a TCP connection without control of the routers/network between you and the target. You **CAN** use PHP to act as a proxy, but that's not "faking".

Comment: The question is: *why?*

Comment: @MarcB thanks, /Fred, if was possible i block.

Comment: having clarification to your question would have helped you here.

Comment: it's not more necessary, InterCity answered me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

You can proxy via a PHP script, but the server will still be visible, if that's what you're asking.

It also boggles my mind why would you do such a thing. The only thing that comes close is a Smurf DDOS attack, which is illegal.

Whatever you are trying to accomplish...

**DON'T!**

Comment: no, it's not ddos attack, i'd like know if exists to be blocked. I'm creating an ads plataform and a lot of users use this method but using false referrer and vpn programs.

Comment: If you are trying to defend against proxying users and adblocks, you could probably just add a list of those that pop up on google, and make the ads display (in english) even on those addresses, no matter where they are or who they are. Or make an one-size-fits-all ad embedded via `<iframe>`.